# Progress Bar - Como fazer assumir valores decimais?

Tags: c#, winforms

Por aprendizado, estou criando um "joguinho" bem besta em C# e faço de uma progress bar a barra de vida, mas preciso diminuir um valor decimal e aparentemente a progress só assume valores int. Como posso fazer ela apresentar valores decimais como 99.2%?

A Progress bar é definida naturalmente com mínimo de 0 e máximo de 100. Linha que faz a diminuição na life:

```
lifeP1.Value -= (int)(ataque2);
```

Comment: não, você não consegue mudar o tipo da variável do controle. Se é necessária aumentar a precisão, você pode aumentar o limite ex: 1000 e na hora de exibir a informação pegar o valor e dividir: `labelVida.Text = (progressBar1.Value / 1000d).ToString("P1");` resultado: `99.2 %`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode setar o valor da propriedade Maximum do ProgressBar pra um valor mais alto e multiplicar. Por exemplo vc seta o Maximum pra 1000 e na hora de setar o Valor vc pode colocar **99.2 * 10 = 992**, ainda dentro do range;

Comment: Entendo. No caso, algum meio prático pra simplesmente forçar o .Value da barra a ser double não há, certo?

Comment: Não, não há, a forma mais simples é essa mesmo, outro colega colocou um comentário, dando outra ideia de como fazer essa conta, mas vai ter sempre q fazer essa conversão.